# QAction doesn't show icon from Pixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap, qaction

For the last couple of hours I'm trying to solve problem with displaying icon in QAction.

The problem is that icon isn't shown, only text decryption is placed on its position 'Roads'.

I've tried to debug it and all the time *QPixmap* is NULL, looks like it can't find file.

Here's how my code looks like:

```
QPixmap icon(":/road.png");
QAction *A1 = new QAction(icon,"Road...", 0);
A1->setIconVisibleInMenu(true);
A1->setVisible(true);
connect(A1, SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(triggeredA1()));
```

I've read [this article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html). 
According to it I've changed my pro file by adding line:

```
RESOURCES = ./res/icons.qrc
```

In src directory I've created subdir 'res' and placed there my icons:

```
-src
  --res
        road.png
        load.gif
        done.gif
```

Here's how my icons.qrc file looks like:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>road.png</file>
        <file>done.gif</file>
        <file>load.gif</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Even after all this manipulations *QPixmap* still *NULL*.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, the file name is `roads.png`, but you refer to it as `road.png`? And put image files in the same directory where your .qrc file lives.

Comment: @vahancho, huh it's just a typo, but thanks :)

Comment: Verify, whether you can open **any** image. For example, `QPixmap icon("path_to_the_image_file"); bool b = icon.isNull();`. If you can, the problem relates to your resource file.

Comment: @vahanaco no problem with two other files.

Comment: Maybe the problem in `road.png` file, or in the image type? Try to use other file instead. Other type: gif, jpeg, etc. Try...

Comment: the first thing you should check is the LOGS. I'm pretty sure that Qt adds  to logs some information what is the problem (for example missing plugin).

Comment: @vahancho looks like the problem really in file type. Everything works fine with jpg, but actually I don't understand why it don't want to open .png.

Comment: @MarekR here's what Qt says: 'libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited'

Comment: @tema, you may miss the png image plugin. Check the plugins/imageformats directory. Or your png file is corrupted png file, or the image of other type, but with inconsistent file name.

Comment: @vahancho yes, you are right: 'libqgif.dylib  libqico.dylib  libqjpeg.dylib libqmng.dylib  libqsvg.dylib  libqtga.dylib  libqtiff.dylib' everything I have in imageformats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I'm using OS X and built Qt4 with MacPorts. For some reason libpng isn't included in build provided by MacPorts. 
So, the solution is to build libpng via MacPorts manually:

```
sudo port install libpng
```

and include this lib to your project by adding following line in .pro file

```
LIBS += -lpng
```

After this steps you can use .png files in your project as it was written above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias and a relative "pseudo-path"

example

```
<qresource prefix="/images">
    <file alias="foobar">resources/images/foobar.png</file>
</qresource>
```

then use pixmap like so

```
<pixmap resource="path/to/resourcefile.qrc">:/images/foobar</pixmap>
```